# MySQL extracting similar data from a group

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

So here is my stripped table from the messages module of an app I'm writing.

[image]

when I run the following command it goes as expected

> SELECT * FROM  `messages`   WHERE to_user = 1 OR from_user = 1  GROUP
>   BY from_user

returns

[image]

The drama is that I want to have just one instance of 2 | 1 or 1 | 2 , since in my app I'm trying to group the messages based on the username that has sent the message. I tried without the OR clause, but then when 1 send a message to 2 the message does not appear until he gets a reply from 2.
1 and 2 are dynamic from php variables

Comment: do NOT put PHP tag because you execute your query from PHP. your question got nothing with PHP

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: Do NOT yell at new users. Please.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha FAR FROM YELLING!

Comment: sorry about that, thanks for adding the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're grouping by username, I would select a single valid list of user ID:

```
SELECT DISTINCT from_user FROM messages WHERE to_user = 1 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT to_user FROM messages WHERE from_user = 1
```

If you don't mind duplicates, `UNION ALL` and removing `DISTINCT` will improve performance.

Comment: UNION will make the list distinct.  UNION ALL will be faster but return duplicates (which may be OK, I don't know).

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot have aggregate and non-aggregate fields in your query result.
2. You can use a function to form the tuple (to_user, from_user):

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT IF(from_user < to_user, from_user, to_user) AS first,
                   IF(from_user < to_user, to_user, from_user) AS second
   FROM   messages
   ```

(not tested, of course).

Comment: Technically [you _can_ `SELECT` nonaggregated columns with `GROUP BY` in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), [but you shouldn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168042/can-i-use-non-aggregate-columns-with-group-by) because its undefined which value will be chosen for the nonaggregated columns.

Comment: That's the point. In practice, MySQL returns the first value from the grouped column, and does not give any hint that this might be semantically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky but it works for me.

```
SELECT n.f, n.t
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT m.from_user AS f, m.to_user AS t
   FROM messages AS m
   WHERE (m.from_user = 1
          OR m.to_user =1)) AS n,
  (SELECT DISTINCT m.from_user AS f, m.to_user AS t
   FROM messages AS m
   WHERE (m.from_user = 1
          OR m.to_user =1)) AS m
WHERE n.f = m.t
  AND m.f = n.t
  AND n.f < m.f;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can append

```
HAVING to_user < from_user
```

Comment: In a message system you cannot guarantee that for every tupal (from,to) a tupel (to,from) exists. Therefore your solution might leave some rows out.

Comment: from pair {n,m} {m,n} you will keep only sorted one; if you can send message to yourself it should be <= operator

Comment: @ertrzyiks: this is incorrect method. what happens in your query if, let say, table has record like to_user = 3, from_user = 1 (3 < 1) == it will fail...

Comment: that is what happened down the rows :(

Comment: im sorry, you are right; Alex Monthy's solution seems handle such situations